# Flutter Google Maps - How to add dynamic text on custom markers

Tags: flutter, google-maps

In my app, I need to display the locations of the deliveries with its corresponding names as soon as the map loads. I've tried this approach from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56172621/place-a-custom-text-under-marker-icon-in-flutter-google-maps-plugin) but the markers are not loading (but it does load if I didn't use the custom marker used in that code I've linked earlier). Where did I go wrong?

For the custom marker:

```
static Future<Uint8List> create(String deliveryName) async {
    final ui.PictureRecorder pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);
    final Paint paint1 = Paint()..color = Colors.grey;
    final int size = 100; 
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size / 2, size / 2), size / 2.0, paint1);
    TextPainter painter = TextPainter(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    painter.text = TextSpan(
      text:
          deliveryName, 
      style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: size / 4, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    );
    painter.layout();
    painter.paint(
      canvas,
      Offset(size / 2 - painter.width / 2, size / 2 - painter.height / 2),
    );

    final img = await pictureRecorder.endRecording().toImage(size, size);
    final data = await img.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return data!.buffer.asUint8List();
  }
```

For the usage:

```
void setMarkers() async{
    _markers.clear();
    print('hi');
    for (Delivery delivery in _deliveries) {
      _markers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(delivery.name),
        position: LatLng(delivery.latitude, delivery.longitude),
        icon:  BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(await CustomMarker.create(delivery.name))
      ));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code to display dynamically changing text inside custom marker on Google Map.

```
  class MyMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyMapState createState() => _MyMapState();
}

class _MyMapState extends State<MyMap> {
  String dynamicText = "Hello World";
  LatLng position = LatLng(37.4219999, -122.0840575);

  Marker marker = Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId("1"),
    position: LatLng(37.4219999, -122.0840575),
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetString(
      "assets/custom_marker_icon.png",
      text: "Hello World",
    ),
  );

  void updateDynamicText(String newDynamicText) {
    setState(() {
      dynamicText = newDynamicText;
      marker = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("1"),
        position: position,
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetString(
          "assets/custom_marker_icon.png",
          text: dynamicText,
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      markers: Set<Marker>.of([marker]),
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: position,
        zoom: 15.0,
      ),
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {},
      onTap: (LatLng newPosition) {
        updateDynamicText("New Text");
      },
    );
  }
}
```